# Gulp tasks with typescript are not detected by visual studio task runner

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I have created gulpfile.ts folder and placed index.ts in there.

### For VS Code:

It works nicely with VS Code as I have

- registered this task as a npm script
- made my build task dependsOn this gulp task

### Problem with Visual Studio 2022 Task Runner.

It only detects task in gulfile.js and not typescript tasks. How do Visual Studio Task Runner can see tasks in gulpfile.ts folder.

### Already Tried

I have tried the JS version and it works fine with bindings on top of file.

I am also doing a workaround for now and not using Task Runner instead in proj file I have placed a `<Taregt beforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">` element that contains one line to execute the `npm run my-script` and that is doing the job of running it every build.

If my workaround is the only or newer option please let me know.